# How add grid field to filter section in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

I use Ui grid in my custom module. I want to add my field to filter section. What parameter required to enable filter on my field.

Here is my filed code

```
<column name="field1">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">field1</item>
            <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

Comment: Let me know if you have any issue

Answer (score 1):

Add `<item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>` to enable filter for your field

Your final code look like:

```
<column name="field1">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">field1</item>
            <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```